# How serious is putting part of separable verbs at the end?

Tags: separable-verb

Is it a rule to put the first part of separable verbs in the end of the sentence, or it is OK not to separate them?

Example:

> heute **stellen** wir euch 12 typisch deutsche gerichte **vor**.

Can it be:

> heute **vorstellen** wir euch 12 typisch deutsche gerichte.

?

Comment: Dead serious. Not separating them will make you sound like Yoda to German ears. (Exactly like Yoda, because that's what they did in German dub.)

Comment: @Janka I thought there was just one rule for the structure of the sentence in German.

Comment: There is one hard word order rule, and all the other word order rules are tendencies, but not separating the verb prefixes when you should isn't a word order rule.

Comment: @Janka It virtually is about the word order!

Comment: Kick the separable prefix from second position. It does not belong there.

Comment: @Janka Kick? What?

Comment: @Sasan don't write it together with the verb. Exceptions: reverse word order, such as: "was, wenn ich mich vorstelle, dass ich König wäre?"

Comment: @Sasan no its not about word order, but rather about lexic. VORstellen und vorSTELLEN would be completely different verbs.

Comment: You’re taught this in grammar lessons. What sliver of evidence makes you think that there would be some kind of optionality to it?

Comment: down-voters please explain!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is very important. The semantic difference would be even bigger than that in English between "[Overthrow](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/overthrow)" and "[throw over](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/throw-over). Basically, placing the prefix the wrong way you are using the wrong word, which sometimes doesn't even exist - as is the case with "vorstellen", that only exists as a separable verb: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/german-english/vorstellen

Another good comparison would be "set **up**" and "**up**set".

To bring a German example off the top of my head, we have *übers**E**tzen* (with the stress on the words root) that means "translate" and we have ***Ü***bersetzen with the stress on the prefix, that means to ferry somebody from one bank of a river to another.

The grammatic topic you may want to look into is "separable verbs in German".

Answer (score 2):

You can put the first part separable verbs every time at the end like you did.
Another example is "einkaufen":

> Heute kaufe ich ein Brot ein.

But if you want to use the verb connected you have to use an auxiliary verb and put the verb at the end like:

> Heute **werde** ich ein Brot einkaufen.

for your sentence it have to be like:

> heute **werden** wir euch 12 typisch deutsche Gerichte vorstellen.